# Local existence of solution of a PDE in the context of manifolds

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, fisher-information, information-geometry

Let $X = (x^1, x^2, \dots, x^n)$ and $Y = (y^1,y^2,\dots,y^n)$
be coordinate systems onto a smooth manifold $M$. Denote by $\partial_i$ the i-th coordinate field of $Y$. Now, I'm trying to solve the PDE system given by

$$y^i = \partial_i f(X).$$

It is part of a proof present in the book "[Information Geometry](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Information_Geometry/pLsyDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Information+Geometry&printsec=frontcover)", more preciselly in the theorem 4.3, which states that

> There exist strictly convex potential functions f(X) and g(Y) satisfying
> $$y^i = \partial_i f(X), \quad x^j = \partial_j g(Y).$$

The proof starts with the argument "the equation $y^i = \partial_i f(X)$ can be solved locally iff
$$\partial_i y^j = \partial_j y^i~'',$$
but I don't understand from where this existence condition comes. Applying the PDE in this condition, I recover the Schwarz's symmetry to second derivatives. Could someone help me understand this argument?

Comment: I do not see any ODE. Do I interpret the equations right in that $X=\nabla g(Y)$ and $Y=\nabla f(X)$? This would then by a system of PDE. How is that construction geometric? It makes no sense that one side of an equation has lower indices, meaning it is covariant, and the other has upper indices, meaning it is contravariant.